# how to prevent site header from moving left when scroll down?

Tags: javascript, css

I am working on a homepage with header, which looks fine when the scrolling bar is not present.

[image]

However, I noticed that when the scrolling bar is available, it pushes the header to its left, making the header mess up with other element.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Below are the css styles I am currently using.

[image]

Also, I am using the [navbar component from reactbootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/), it seems that it contains some generic styles cooperating with my added styles.

Below are these related styles.

[image]

Any help would be appreaciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```css
.site-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  //...
}
```

Comment: its not working although i think you are approaching it, please check out my update in the question.

Comment: It's hard to tell what is in the image, is this a progress bar that shows how far the page is scrolled? and what is the difference on the x-axis, I don't see a difference in the header position that it looks further left

Comment: this is not a progress bar but a header bar that shows on the top of the page. and what do you mean by difference on x-axis?

Comment: I can't tell from this image how the header is pushed to the left. You need to upload a better screenshot, I can't see what I'm supposed to be looking at here.